# Как в запросе подсчитать количество записей по статусу?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица `orders`, которая помимо прочих содержит поле status. Поле status может содержать значения `R,N,S,A,F`.

Нужно получить в результе запроса в колонке `ALL` все заказы без учета статуса, в колонке "Готовые заказы" со статусом `R,F`, а в колонке "Не готовые заказы" со статусами `N,I,A,S`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Уже разобралась

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
with t (status) as ( 
    select trim (column_value)
    from xmlTable ('"R","N","I","S","A","F"'), (select 1 from dual connect by level<=9)
)
select 
    count (*) "All", 
    count (case when status in ('R','F')         then 1 end) "Completed orders",
    count (case when status in ('N','I','S','A') then 1 end) "Not completed orders"
from t
/

       All Completed orders Not completed orders
---------- ---------------- --------------------
        54               18                   36
```